# Removing article with ID from URL

Tags: php

Im building this blogg site and finally got everything considering uploading multiple pictures to one news article done.

Now my second step is to remove an article with following pictures to it.
Everything is set in the database so all i need is an ID from the news article.

When i press remove button on a article it shows the ID up in the URL... Im wondering how to get the specifik ID int from the URL and IF there is an smarter approach. It must be OOP and objectoriented apporach.

Code looks like this:

This is the looping out each article and notice $current_id that i put into a button to show in the url when its pressed

```
    public function doOutputArticles($newsList, $pictureList)
    {

        $result = '';
        foreach($newsList as $news)
        {
           $result .= '<ul>';   
           $current_id = $news->dbNewsID;
           $result .= '<li class="bloggNewsHeader">'.$news->dbHeader.'</li>';
           $result .= '<li class="bloggNews">'.$news->dbNews.'</li>';
           $result .= '<li class="bloggNewsDate">'.$news->dbNewsDate.'</li>';
           foreach($pictureList as $pic)
           {
              if($pic->dbNewsID == $current_id)
              {
                $result .= '<li class="bloggNewsPicID">'.$pic->dbPictureID.'</li>';
                $result .= '<img class="bloggNewsPic" src="./images/'.$pic->dbPicture.'"alt="some_text">';
              }  
           }
           $result .= "
                        <form id='' method='get'>
                            <input type='hidden'    name='$current_id'/>
                            <input type='submit'      name='removeArticle' value='Ta bort inlägg' />
                        </form>";

           $result .= '</ul>';
        }
        return "<div id='filesLoaded'>". $result ."</div>";

    }
```

`

After this is done, i press a button to remove specific article and then the ID shows in the URL, now this method is meant to GET the specific INT/NUMBER ID in the URL but HOW?

```
public function GetSelectedID()
    {       
        $ID = $_GET[self::$articleId];
        echo $ID;

        if(is_null($ID) || empty($ID))
        {
             return null;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $ID;
            return $ID;
        }

    }
```

`
Kind regards /Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a form, a simple link would do and be clearer.  You should be using a different endpoint for deletion rather than looking for "removeArticle".   This would be more OO since it would pave the path towards creating a specific Action Controller for each function rather than having one sprawling endpoint full of conditionals.  Then you can have a consistent parameter (ideally within the URL path) of something like "articleId" that you are extracting from the URL.  You'd also ideally want to redirect to the listing page upon completion to keep functionality focused in each method and also as a practice to avoid double posting issues (though this example is idempotent so it wouldn't be overly important).

Comment: Sounds great, I've done almoste everything you've tip about but stuck at one thing now. Can't get the url that the link is posting. My $_GET doesnt respond to that for ex: /articleID= is beeing added. Is it even possible to use $_GET with a link? :S

Comment: If you're just using GET then stick with QueryString parameters for now.  So have a link to something like `/blog/delete?articleId=something`, and then you should have access to `$_GET['articleId']`.  Extracting from the URL path could be added later but is a larger question.

Comment: Yeah, weird thing is that it doesnt respond to it. My ex is:

    `"<a href='articleId=$current_id'>Delete</a>";`

I get to page that doesnt exist, something like `site/articleId=30`.. Thats fine, but then i put `header(Location: mySite);` in the $_GET function if its true...but it never appears true. Wondering what im doing wrong, it works perfect with a form and buttons but thing is with link the url is much prettier and readable for humans^^ Do you know what im doing wrong?

Comment: the href should be something like `delete?articleId=$current_id` which would point to a `delete` endpoint relative to your present path with articleId available to `$_GET`

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much for your anwsers and time! I appriciate it a lot! Take care!